# Background property behaving unexpectedly in CSS

Tags: html, css

[Actual webpage](http://jacobcrofts.github.io/test.html)

I'm trying to display code snippets on my webpage. I'm a CSS novice and having trouble creating a dark background on which to display my code snippets.

When I create a class called "test" (which should override all other background specifications, right?) and assign it a color property of blue and a background property of black, the color blue shows up within pre tags but the background remains the default color.

When I switch to span tags and assign the class there instead, both properties work as I command. But I don't want to use span because my instructors say non-semantic tags are bad practice. Something tells me that there's some inherent property of pre tags that I need to override somehow.

Any ideas? I can post the code here if that's proper/necessary.

Edit: I posted an abbreviated version of the code here. I tested it, and got the same issue here. Hopefully with less code it will be easier to pinpoint the problem.

Here's the HTMl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/test.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <pre class="test">test</pre>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the CSS:

```
.test {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: black;
}

pre {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 0px;
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: @amdixon done (I removed the irrelevant parts)

Comment: HTML would be fine, too.

Comment: Remove line-height: 0px; and you will see black background....

Comment: @nevermind Just as you said, I see the black background now. So that fixes my primary issue. But I put that in there in the first place because there was too much space between my lines. How might I make my lines closer together without using line-height?

Answer (score 0):

The more specific the rule, the more likely it will be to override a parent class or id. Give this one a shot...

```
.snippets div{
  background-color: #F00;
}
.snippets div.no_code{
  background-color: #000;
}
```

---

```
<div class="snippets">
   <div>&nbsp;</div>
   <div>&nbsp;</div>
   <div>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="no_code">&nbsp;</div>
   <div>&nbsp;</div>
   <div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with background-color property of pre tag?

Please check my codepen link. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaydao

```
HTML:
  <body>
    <p>
      <pre>test</pre>
    </p>
  </body>

CSS:
.test {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: black;
}

pre {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:#DDFFDD;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to use `!important` on your class because it's already defined the color property in another class...

```
.code{
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

```css
.box{
  width: 250px;
  height: 20xp;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
.code{
    background-color: #000 !important;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box code">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box code">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box code">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box no_code">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box code">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box no_code">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="box no_code">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't change anything for me.